# How to get the list of users and also their UID from the firebase real time DB

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to Angular and Firebase , so please help me. How can i get the UID of the user and also get the whole user list and show it in ngFor , i am using https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/ for connecting with angular

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/teVl7.png): [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume, you've multiple `user` objects under the `/users` node. To access the entire `/users` node as an array `<User[]>` or simply `<any[]>` with the user `id` property, please try the following to get the observable which when subscribed would return the array with key (or user id).

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let user of users$ | async">
         ID: {{ user.id}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  users$: Observable<any[]>;
  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.users$ = db.list('users')
                     .snapshotChanges()
                     .pipe(map((users: any[]) => users.map(user => ({ id: user.key, ...user.payload.val() })))); 
  }
}
```

Using `snapshotChanges()` method returns the firebase node data value along with its metadata as opposed to `valueChanges()` which returns only the data payload.

Thus, while using the `snapshotChanges()`, we should map (remember to import `map` operator from `rxjs/operators`) the snapshot and for each `user` object in the array, map with the additional property `id` and access the auto-assigned firebase key with the `key` property value. This, we can access in the template when subscribed.

Here, for every `user` object in the array, we are assigning only the `id` using the `key` from the metadata and the `user` object itself using the `...` spread operator. We have not used any other metadata, just to keep the object light.

I hope this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , i will try this